# Rspec test with devise mailer sending job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got functionality where a user gets reminder to complete registration after 2, 10 and 26 days after first registration. How to test if email will be not sending after eg. 6 days after first registration?

**jobs/remind_users_without_banker_about_unconfirmed_account.rb**

```
class RemindUsersWithoutBankerAboutUnconfirmedAccount < ApplicationJob
  NUMBER_OF_DAYS_SINCE_CREATION = [2, 10, 26].freeze

  def perform
    RemindUnconfirmedUsersWithoutBanker.call(NUMBER_OF_DAYS_SINCE_CREATION)
  end
end
```

this is a service where all action is made

**services/remind_unconfirmed_users_without_banker.rb**

```
class RemindUnconfirmedUsersWithoutBanker < ApplicationService
  def call(number_of_days)
    return Failure(:invalid_value) if invalid?(number_of_days)

    users_to_mail = unconfirmed_users_not_created_by_bank_employees(number_of_days)
    return Failure(:no_matching_users) if users_to_mail.empty?

    resend_invitation(users_to_mail)
    Success(nil)
  end

  private

  def unconfirmed_users_not_created_by_bank_employees(number_of_days)
    days_mapped_with_date = number_of_days.map { |day| day.days.ago.to_date }

    User.where("users.bank_employee_id IS ?
                AND users.confirmed_at IS ?
                AND DATE(users.created_at) IN (?)",
               nil,
               nil,
               days_mapped_with_date)
  end

  def invalid?(number_of_days)
    number_of_days.any? { |number_of_day| !number_of_day.is_a?(Integer) || number_of_day < 1 }
  end

  def resend_invitation(users_to_mail)
    users_to_mail.each do |user|
      Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(user, user.confirmation_token).deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

And I have one spec where failure is returned and spec is green but it doesn't exactly simulate of sending an e-mail

```
RSpec.describe RemindUnconfirmedUsersWithoutBanker do
  subject(:remind_unconfirmed_users) { described_class.call(number_of_days) }

  let(:number_of_days) { [2, 10, 26] }

  before do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    allow(InvitationMailer).to receive_message_chain(:confirmation_instructions, :deliver)
  end

  context "when created_at equals to 6 days" do
    it "does not invite user again" do
      create_list(:user, 2, created_at: 6.days.ago, confirmed_at: nil)
      expect(remind_unconfirmed_users).to eq(Failure(:no_matching_users))
    end
  end
```

Is there better way to check if these emails are send only on days that are mentioned (2, 10, 26)?

Comment: it's not completely clear to me what exactly your problem is, but if you want to making testing easier, write your code so that it's easy to test. in this case, i would extract a finder method that handles the numer of days stuff and test that extensively so that i can use it within the job with confidence.

Comment: @phoet thanks for your response! my problem is how to test if these emails were sent or not 6 days after registration (they shouldn't be sent).

Comment: that's what i've understood and that's exactly what my advise aims at. write a finder method on `User` test that to return only the desired results and simply use it in your service class. that way you can test the retrieval in isolation which makes the test trivial.

Comment: Ok @phoet so I should create another service with method similar to `def invalid?(number_of_days)` ? I don't understand how it could be easier to test? Probably this will be in line with single responsibility principle but to be honest, I don't know how I can improve it.